# Trying to downgrade code in older react version

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I am trying to run the following code in older react version. I am getting errors like cant resolve reactdom/client. I tried to play around with index.js function, then started to get errors like expecting string in index.js line 7 (which is App/) but got obj, etc, etc

I need some hints on how to downgrade the code to React 16 as I am trying to merge with another package which has lots of code in React 16. Any hints, directions to make the code run old react version will be appreciated.

https://github.com/olawanlejoel/react-metamask-ether

below is my package.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "ethers": "^5.0.18",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.10.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
```

while the dependencies of the github code are newer versions

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "ethers": "^5.6.6",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: 1) Create a branch new project for the target version. 2) Copy your source. 3) Manually edit package.json as needed.  4) Do a trial build.  5) Rinse/repeat.  NOTE: If you're using version control (e.g. Git) maybe you can just check out an older version (potentially bypassing steps 1 and 2).

Comment: I'd recommend updating the other package

Comment: Why updating the other package will be easier? Can you explain? Is React 18 will run everything under React 16